# Match a certain subset of nodes by (global) position number

Tags: xpath, genshi

Is there an XPath syntax to match, for instance, the occurrences numbered 2,3,5,7,11,13 of a certain kind of node? That is, the same result as the union of

```
//item[2]
//item[3]
//item[5]
...
```

but in a single expression.

(Use case: I am using a Genshi transformer to match and remove a set of nodes. I can't match and remove them in successive expressions, because their indices would change inbetween.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using XPath `position()` like for example :

```
//item[position()=2 or position()=3 or position()=5 ...]
```

or maybe using parentheses if I understand correctly what you mean by "global position number" :

```
(//item)[position()=2 or position()=3 or position()=5 ...]
```

Comment: My simple test shows that the same happen with `//item[2]`, that expression selects the 2nd `item` within the same parent. As for global position, the XPath should've been `(//item)[2]`

Comment: Yes you are right, I was testing it at the same time. Sorry for the false alarm.